# I want to use gmail api in jwt way

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, gmail, jwt, gmail-api

Can I authenticate using jwt-gmail api?

google developer : 'https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google'

It says that only the api at this address can use this method.

But I can not find the gmail api here.

Can the gmail api only use the access token method using oauth 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by  jwt-gmail api.  That being said.

I think your looking at the wrong library try  [google-apis-nodejs-clinet](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client).

Gmail api facts normal user gmail accounts can only be accessed using Oauth2 if its a gsuite account then you can use domain wide deligation and user a service account